# Does Naseem Hamed violate the Marquess of Queensberry Rules in this video?

Tags: rules, officiating, boxing

Rule four of the Marquess of Queensberry Rules:

> If either man fall through weakness or otherwise, he must get up unassisted, ten seconds be allowed to do so, the other man meanwhile to return to his corner; and when the fallen man is on his legs the round is to be resumed and continued until the three minutes have expired. If one man fails to come to the scratch in the ten seconds allowed, it shall be in the power of the referee to give his awart in favour of the other man.

[Video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlQ6l3un48Q&t=18m5s)

Here we see Prince Naseem Hamed and Augie Sanchez get tangled up and fall, thought there was obviously no knockdown, just a pair of slips.  Hamed shows admirable sportsman ship in helping Sanchez to his feet, but the Marquess of Queensberry Rules are pretty clear on this point:

> **If either man fall through weakness *or otherwise*, he must get up *unassisted***

They both fell, not "through weakness", but "otherwise";  Naz got up mostly "unassisted", although the ref at least tried to help him;  but in any case, Sanchez clearly received help in standing back up.

#### Did Hamed technically violate the fourth Queensberry Rule?